# InflateException error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I keep getting that error when starting the activity that has fragment.

This is the overview of my code:

*Home* activity is started from *Splash* screen activity

**home.xml** (Each fragment has 50% `layout_weight`)

```
<LinearLayout>
    <fragment android:name="com.example.test.FragmentClass1" ...>
    <fragment android:name="com.example.test.FragmentClass2" ...>
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment1.xml**

```
<LinearLayout>
    //some EditTexts and Buttons here
<LinearLayout>
```

**fragment2.xml**

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ListView ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

**FragmentClass1.java**

```
public class FragmentClass1 extends Fragment{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**FragmentClass2.java**

```
public class FragmentClass2 extends ListFragment{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Home.java**

```
public class Home extends Activity{
    public View onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        //still empty
    }
}
```

The error log is this:

```
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at com.example.test.Home.onCreate(Home.java:16)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    ... 11 more
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.test.Fragment1 cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4709)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214):    ... 21 more
```

Any solution? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to use the Android Support package's backport of fragments, you need to have your activity inherit from `FragmentActivity` (or from something else that inherits from `FragmentActivity`, like `SherlockFragmentActivity`).

---

**UPDATE**

The key line from your stack trace is:

```
12-09 20:39:00.317: E/AndroidRuntime(18214): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.test.Fragment1 cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
```

Now, there is nothing in your supplied source code that is named `com.example.test.Fragment1`. If this is really what you have in your listings as `com.example.test.FragmentClass1`, then presumably the `Fragment` you are inheriting from is not `android.app.Fragment`. Most likely, in that case, it is `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` -- the `Fragment` class from the backport. If this is the case, change the import statement (and any other flawed ones in the rest of your code base).

Comment: I planned to make for ICS 4.0.3+ only. So it should be okay right?

Comment: @DarcCode: Yes, but the error message feels like you are running on an older version of Android, if that is all there is to it. If there is more to the stack trace (e.g., "Caused by"), please post it.

Comment: I'm running it in Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.2.1 By the way I have just updated the full error log. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, yeah it is caused by the `v4.app` import. Actually I changed the `Fragment1` in my code into `FragmentClass1` in my question just to differentiate it with the xml name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write

```
super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

in your onCreateView method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I already got the right answer. And I don't think we need to add super

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.
and I fixed it by adding the following lines in manifest.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```